# What is the correct structure to use in a sentence containing 'once' as the subordinate conjunction?

Tags: grammar, verbs, clauses, subordinate-clauses, subordinators

In a sentence containing a conjunction, what are the correct verb forms to be used in the two clauses? For example:

> I would also suggest that once all these items are established, they must be added to the employee handbook.

I feel that "must be added" is not correct, but I also can't figure out what would be the correct form. ***will***/***shall***/***should***?

For further context, "these items" refers to a list of action plan suggestions.

I did some googling, and went through the relevant grammar notes from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/once), but it doesn't cover the more complex structure that I'm looking for.

Comment: You can't suggest a "must"; _suggest_ is too mild for that. It should be _should_.

Comment: @JohnLawler That makes sense. So would you suggest _should_ or _be_ as suggested in the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way of phrasing this sentence would be:

> I would also suggest that, once all of these items are established,
> *they be added* to the employee handbook.

Comment: Except you only need one _that_, which can go either place it appears here, but not both.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks, fixed.

Comment: The question is actually impossible to answer, because it depends on what exactly the speaker is trying to say.  Grammatically the sentence is grammatically and semantically standard English.  How can we be sure that the speaker/writer is not strongly urging the taking of this obvious step?  For example, published official regulations often distinguish between the use of 'must' to indicate a legal requirement and 'should' to indicate a recommendation.  The sentence is typically British in its cautions use of "I should also suggest".  But that is a matter of style, not of grammar or semantics.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, @Tuffy.

Comment: @Tuffy This is not a legal text and I wasn't asking about the legal meaning of the sentence. I just couldn't figure out the correct structure as in the verb form, rather than choice of the modal verb. This answer helped me understand that and I sent in my email now. :)